# Dynamics AX 2012 debugger opens by itself, no breakpoint

Tags: debugging, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a strange problem. A dev AX2012 enviroment has a form that once in the while went into a continous loop on update (lots of updates happening since this was related to work time logging). When this happened, the AX debugger started by itself without any breakpoints and not even at a line in code that was relevant for solving the problem, but **always the same line**.

Not that I'm complaing, as I found and fixed the problem, but I'd really, really want to know why the debugger started?

Comment: "...always the same line."  Out of curiosity...  Was it one of the Tax* handling classes?

Comment: No, completely new client-specific classes, tables and forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you were in a continuous loop. I've had this problem too on AX 2009.

My scenario was: There was code in the update method that did changecompany() and did an update of a record there, then it did the same in that company and so on (back and forth between companies, endlessly). After a while the loop stops and the debugger is shown on a random line, but always the same line.

Answer (score 1):

If breakpoints are enabled in the user setup, and AX experiences some errors like null pointer reference, then AX displays an error and subsequently starts the debugger.

You solved your problem or recompiled your code, and the problem is gone.

Comment: I guess an error was there, but it could not show it. If you have access to AX kernel code and can reproduce the problem, you can debug it yourself! It is otherwise purely speculative.

Comment: Hmm. I see your point but am not satisfied. I want my error messages visible :D